# Unable to Access Secured APIs After OTP-Based Login and Obtaining JWT Token

Tags: spring-security, jwt, one-time-password

I am currently working on an application that incorporates OTP verification for signup and signin APIs on the app side. I have opted to use the phoneNumber as the username and have excluded the usage of passwords. The backend of the application is built using Spring Boot 3. After successfully obtaining the JWT token from the signup API, I am facing an issue when attempting to access secured APIs. I am seeking assistance to troubleshoot and resolve this problem. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

  @Autowired
  AuthService authService;

  @PostMapping("/signup")
  public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerCreateRequestDTO customerCreateRequestDTO) {
    String x = authService.registerUser(customerCreateRequestDTO);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(x);
  }

}
```

```
@Service
public class AuthService {
  
  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  CustomerService customerService;

  @Autowired
  JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  public String registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerCreateRequestDTO customerCreateRequestDTO) {
    if (customerService.existsByPhoneNumber(customerCreateRequestDTO.getPhoneNumber())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error: PhoneNumber is already use!");
    }

    if (customerService.existsByEmail(customerCreateRequestDTO.getEmail())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error: Email is already in use!");
    }

    Customer customer = customerService.createNewCustomer(customerCreateRequestDTO);

    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(customer);
    return jwt;

  }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer implements UserDetails {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String firstName;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String lastName;

  private String email;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String phoneNumber;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String address;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Role role;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Account account;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Date createdAt;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Date updatedAt;

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.role.name()));
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
   return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
   return true;
  }
}
```

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
    body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
    body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
  }

}
```

```
@Component
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Autowired
  private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @Autowired
  private CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = parseJwt(request);
      if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
          Customer customer = customerDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              customer,
              null,
              customer.getAuthorities());
          authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
          logger.info(filterChain.toString());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      return headerAuth.substring(7);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

  @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${app.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private int jwtExpirationMs;

  public String generateJwtToken(Customer customer) {
    return Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(customer.getPhoneNumber())
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
        .signWith(key(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
        .compact();
  }
  
  private Key key() {
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret));
  }

  public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
        .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
  }

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
    try {
      Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build().parse(authToken);
      return true;
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CustomerDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public Customer loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.findByPhoneNumber(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
    return customer;
  }

}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customerDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: writing custom security is bad practice, and using jwts as session tokens is insecure. Stop writing custom security and read the spring documentation on how to properly implement correct security instead of following badly written blogs and tutorials

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will reconsider my approach and review the Spring documentation for better security implementation.

Comment: Hello @Toerktumlare , I followed your suggestion and switched from custom security to Spring Security. However, I'm facing an issue where the SecurityContextHolder is being set to an anonymous SecurityContext. Could you please assist me in resolving this? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i cant help unless you update your question to the actual code then used

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I have updated the code files. Could you please review them and offer your assistance?

Comment: This code is still using custom authentication filters and custom jwtfilters. You clearly have not read the spring security documentation. Stop following poor outdated blogs/tutorials and read the docs